# Proportionality of linear functionals

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over a field $\mathbb{F}$. Suppose that $f,g$ belong to $V^{*}=\operatorname{Hom}(V,\mathbb{F})$
and have the property that if $f(v)=0$, then $g(v)=0$. Prove that $f$ and $g$ proportional in $V^{*}$.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $\dim V = n$. If $f = 0$ then clearly $g = 0$. Otherwise, $\dim \ker f = n - 1$ so choose a basis $v_1, \dots, v_n$ of $V$ such that $v_1,\dots, v_{n-1}$ form a basis of $\ker f$. Since $f(v_n) \neq 0$, we can define $\lambda := \frac{g(v_n)}{f(v_n)}$. Then

$$ (\lambda f)(v_i) = \lambda f(v_i) = 0 = g(v_i)  $$

for $1 \leq i \leq n - 1$ and

$$ (\lambda f)(v_n) = \frac{g(v_n)}{f(v_n)} f(v_n) = g(v_n)$$

showing that $\lambda f = g$.